# How to set New Variable value from Old Variable value but with Object / Model Data

Tags: flutter

How to set New Variable value from Old Variable value, if New Variable value changed the Old Variable not follow the changes. with Condition of type Data is Object?
I actually asked about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74685849/13096991)

But the problem I found confused me. Just look for the example code:

```
void main() {
  final Data mainData = Data(
    data: [
      Group(
        id: 1,
        groupName: 'Assault Riffle',
        weaponItems: [
          Weapon(id: 1, name: 'Ak47'),
          Weapon(id: 2, name: 'M4'),
        ],
      ),
      Group(
        id: 2,
        groupName: 'SMG',
        weaponItems: [
          Weapon(id: 3, name: 'MP5'),
          Weapon(id: 4, name: 'Dual UZI'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

  final Data newData = Data(data: mainData.data); // create new Instance
  print('before mainData: ${mainData.data?[0].weaponItems?[0].name}'); // mainData: Ak47
      
  newData.data?[0].weaponItems?[0].name = 'SCAR';

  print('newData: ${newData.data?[0].weaponItems?[0].name}'); // newData: SCAR
  print('after mainData: ${mainData.data?[0].weaponItems?[0].name}'); // mainData: Scar (should Ak47)
}
```

As you can see the `newData` that I changed made the data in `mainData` change even though I had created a new instance.

The model data class:

```
class Data {
  List<Group>? data;

  Data({this.data});
}

class Group {
  int? id;
  List<Weapon>? weaponItems;
  String? groupName;

  Group({
    this.id,
    this.weaponItems,
    this.groupName,
  });
}

class Weapon {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  Weapon({this.id, this.name});
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: @SayyidJ When I create a new variable `newData` from new Instance of `mainData`, then I changes the value on the new variable. I want the `mainData` not to follow the changes that I do on the `newData`. but the code above makes the value on `mainData` follow the changes

Comment: I also got confused in the beginning....confusion between pass by value and pass by reference.......

Comment: I am upvoting as it may help others to focus.....its question regarding pointer to object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a deep copy of the structure to do what you want to do. This is a way to do it:

```
final Data newData = Data(
    data: mainData.data
        ?.map((group) => Group(
            id: group.id,
            weaponItems: group.weaponItems
                ?.map((weapon) => Weapon(id: weapon.id, name: weapon.name))
                .toList(),
            groupName: group.groupName))
        .toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

i created adjustment to your modelling and create custom function like `copyWith` and `replaceWeapon`, it will come handy if you need to change something.

the result :

```
final Data mainData = Data(
    data: [
      Group(
        id: 1,
        groupName: 'Assault Riffle',
        weaponItems: [
          Weapon(id: 1, name: 'Ak47'),
          Weapon(id: 2, name: 'M4'),
        ],
      ),
      Group(
        id: 2,
        groupName: 'SMG',
        weaponItems: [
          Weapon(id: 3, name: 'MP5'),
          Weapon(id: 4, name: 'Dual UZI'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

  final Data newData = mainData.copyAndReplaceWeaponAt(
      indexGroup: 0, indexWeapon: 0, newWeapon: Weapon(name: 'SCAR'));

  print('newData: ${newData.data[0].weaponItems[0].name}'); // newData: SCAR
  print('after mainData: ${mainData.data[0].weaponItems[0].name}'); //----> AK47
```

modelling :

```
class Data {
  final List<Group> data;
  Data({List<Group>? data}) : data = data ?? [];

  Data copyAndReplaceWeaponAt(
      {required int indexGroup,
      required int indexWeapon,
      required Weapon newWeapon}) {
    return Data(
        data: List.generate(data.length, (index) {
      if (index == indexGroup) {
        List<Weapon> weapons =
            List.generate(data[indexGroup].weaponItems.length, (index) {
          if (index == indexWeapon) {
            return data[indexGroup]
                .weaponItems[indexWeapon]
                .copyWith(id: newWeapon.id, name: newWeapon.name);
          }
          return data[indexGroup].weaponItems[index];
        });
        return data[index].copyWith(weaponItems: weapons);
      }
      return data[index];
    }));
  }
}

class Group {
  final int? id;
  final List<Weapon> weaponItems;
  final String? groupName;

  Group({this.id, this.groupName, List<Weapon>? weaponItems})
      : weaponItems = weaponItems ?? [];

  Group copyWith({
    int? id,
    List<Weapon>? weaponItems,
    String? groupName,
  }) {
    return Group(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        weaponItems: weaponItems ?? this.weaponItems,
        groupName: groupName ?? this.groupName);
  }
}

class Weapon {
  final int? id;
  final String? name;

  Weapon({this.id, this.name});

  Weapon copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? name,
  }) {
    return Weapon(id: id ?? this.id, name: name ?? this.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you access the data. When you copy an array in dart you don't copy it but you actually copy the pointer to the array.
Copy your array elements 1 by 1 and you won't have this problem anymore.

Replace your :

```
final Data newData = Data(data: mainData.data); // create new Instance
```

by

```
final Data newData = Data();
for(Group group in mainData.data){ 
 newData.data.add(group); 
}
```

Comment: Is that the only way? It really hurts if I have thousands of lists (about the performance).

Comment: @SeptianDika replace your : 
final Data newData = Data(data: mainData.data); // create new Instance
by 

final Data newData = Data();
for(Group group in mainData.data){
  newData.data.add(group);
}

and see if your problem is solved

After that I didn't personally push my research on the subject so I couldn't help you more but if that's your problem you can better direct your research.